# 'b' Added to file name when trying to load data file in Jupyter

Tags: csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

When trying to load a data file into a Jupyter notebook I get the following error message

```
File b'data_file.csv' does not exist: b'data_file.csv'
```

Following suggestions I can find online on this problem, I tried the following variations, including specifying the full path and utf encoding

```
pd.read_csv("data_file.csv")
pd.read_csv("C:\\FULL_PATH\\EBI\\data_file.csv")
pd.read_csv(r"data_file.csv")
pd.read_csv(r"C:\\FULL_PATH\\EBI\\data_file.csv")
pd.read_csv("data_file.csv",encoding='utf-8')
pd.read_csv("C:\\FULL_PATH\\EBI\\data_file.csv",encoding='utf-8')
pd.read_csv(r"data_file.csv",encoding='utf-8')
pd.read_csv(r"C:\\FULL_PATH\\EBI\\data_file.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

as well as

```
pd.read_csv('C:\\FULL_PATH\\EBI\\"data_file.csv"')
```

However, all of these yield the same error message
File b'data_file.csv' does not exist: b'data_file.csv'

Not sure if it is helpful to add that the Jupyter notebook is being run on a Windows Server 2012 platform. Please note that I checked using os.getcwd() that the full path is indeed as quoted above.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: try to use .decode() method on path string

Comment: pd.read_csv("data_file.csv".decode())
and
pd.read_csv("data_file.csv".decode('UTF-8'))

both give the error message "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is in your working directory, could you try:

```
import os

file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"data_file.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```